# MYSQL sorting column with mid sentence number correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a column in a MySQL database named `title` that is a varchar(255) datatype. When sorting by `title ASC` the rows sort in this order:

```
Example - A1 Some description
Example - A2 A different description
Example - A20 Some other wording
Example - A21 Different text
Example - A3 Some text
Example - A4 Some final text
Example item that does not follow pattern
```

Whereas I need it to be sorted as follows:

```
Example - A1 Some description
Example - A2 A different description
Example - A3 Some text
Example - A4 Some final text
Example - A20 Some other wording
Example - A21 Different text
Example item that does not follow pattern
```

I have tried using this query:

```
SELECT *,
   CAST(title AS UNSIGNED) casted_title
FROM example_table
ORDER BY casted_title,
         title
```

But that didn't help as `casted_title` comes back empty for all rows.

I also tried this query:

```
SELECT *,
   BIN(title) AS bintitle
FROM cycle_tracker_event_categories
ORDER BY bintitle,
         title
```

That didn't help either. All rows return `bintitle` as 0.

Is there a way to sort in the desired way considering the numbers in question are mid sentence and may or may not be alongside a letter?

EDIT:

Not all items in the list follow the same pattern beginning with "Example - ". Some don't contain any numbers at all, I've just focussed on those above because those were the ones I was having issues with.

Comment: Is there always a `-`, followed by a space, followed by a char like `A` and then a number? If so do you want the rows sorted by that number only and nothing else?

Comment: Some rows don't have a number at all. Sorry, I should have mentioned that in my question. I'll update it now. Thanks.

Comment: Converting a string to a number always returns `0` if it doesn't begin with a number. It won't search for the number in the middle.

Comment: If it has a number is it always after `Example - A`?

Comment: Is there some way you can add a new column to the table with the number you want to order by? Even if you can do it this way, it will be very inefficient.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the substring after the `Example - A` prefix before you convert it to a number that you can order by. Otherwise it will just convert to `0`.

```
ORDER BY IF(title LIKE 'Example - A%', 0+SUBSTR(title, LENGTH('Example - A')), 99999)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work unfortunately as there isn't a predictable pattern. My apologies, I thought I'd made that clear in the question. Looks like my only option is to follow your comment and add an additional column and sort by that instead. Thanks.